# Acrescentar a data seguinte sempre que crio um linha nova

Tags: javascript

Criei uma tabela para fazer `insert`, `update` e `delete` com `datatables`. Pretendo ao adicionar uma nova linha, na coluna data, que preencha automaticamente com a data seguinte à linha anterior. Exemplo. Na última linha tenho a data 05-07-2019, quando adicionar uma linha, o campo data fique logo preenchido com 06-07-2019. E também quando chega ao final do mês começar com a data do mês seguinte.

Código:

```
class CellDate{
constructor( start_date ){
    this.date = start_date;
}
getNextDate(){
    this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);
    return this.date;
}
}

var DateIndexer = new CellDate(new Date());

$('#add').click(function(){

var html = '<tr>';
html += '<td contenteditable id="data1">'+DateIndexer.getNextDate()+'</td>';
html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
html += '</tr>';
$('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
});

$(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
var data = $('#data1').text();
var responsavel = $('#data2').text();
var apoio = $('#data3').text();
var elementos = $('#data4').text();
var elementos1 = $('#data5').text();
if(data != '' && responsavel != '' && apoio != '' && elementos != '' && elementos1 != '')
{
 $.ajax({
 url:"./insert",
 method:"POST",
 data:{data:data, responsavel:responsavel, apoio:apoio, elementos:elementos, elementos1:elementos1},
 success:function(data)
 {
  $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
  $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
  fetch_data();
 }
 });
 setInterval(function(){
 $('#alert_message').html('');
 }, 5000);
 }
 else
{
 alert("Os campos são de preencimento obrigatório!");
}
});
```

Mas tenho dois problemas:

1º o formato da data, retorna assim:

```
Wed Jul 03 2019 14:56:57 GMT+0100 (Hora de verão da Europa Ocidental) e pretendia que fosse por exemplo: 03-07-2019
```

2º problema:

Não começa na data que existe na linha anterior, começa na data do dia atual

Comment: A tabela sempre já vai começar com uma linha?

Comment: @Sam A primeira vez a ser preenchida começa sem linhas, depois disso tem sempre linhas preenchidas

Comment: E quando não tiver linhas, que data que vai ser? Porque não vai ter uma data anterior pra comparar.

Comment: @Sam quando não tem linhas, vai pegar no primeiro dia do mês seguinte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma função que vai retornar a data no formato `dd-mm-aaaa`:

```
function novaData(d){
   var dia = d.getDate().toString();
   dia = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia;
   var mes = (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
   mes = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes;
   var ano = d.getFullYear();
   return dia+"-"+mes+"-"+ano;
}
```

Na função `getNextDate()` coloque um `if` para duas condições:

```
if(){
  // caso já exista uma linha com uma data
}else{
  // caso NÃO exista uma linha com uma data
}
```

A função ficará assim:

```
getNextDate(){
   if($('#user_data tbody tr').length){
      var ultima_data = $("#user_data tbody tr:first td:first").text().trim().split("-");
      var ultimo_dia = +ultima_data[0];
      var ultimo_mes = +ultima_data[1];
      var ultimo_ano = +ultima_data[2];
      this.date.setDate(ultimo_dia);
      this.date.setMonth(ultimo_mes-1);
      this.date.setYear(ultimo_ano);
      this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate()+1);
   }else{
      this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + 1);
      this.date.setDate(1);
   }
   return  novaData(this.date);
}
```

**Teste quando não existe uma linha:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var data = $('#data1').text();
   var responsavel = $('#data2').text();
   var apoio = $('#data3').text();
   var elementos = $('#data4').text();
   var elementos1 = $('#data5').text();
   if(data != '' && responsavel != '' && apoio != '' && elementos != '' && elementos1 != '')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"./insert",
     method:"POST",
     data:{data:data, responsavel:responsavel, apoio:apoio, elementos:elementos, elementos1:elementos1},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Os campos são de preencimento obrigatório!");
   }
  });
  
function novaData(d){
   var dia  = d.getDate().toString();
   dia = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia;
   var mes  = (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
   mes = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes;
   var ano = d.getFullYear();
   return dia+"-"+mes+"-"+ano;
}
  
  class CellDate{
    constructor( start_date ){
        this.date = start_date;
    }
getNextDate(){
   if($('#user_data tbody tr').length){
      var ultima_data = $("#user_data tbody tr:first td:first").text().trim().split("-");
      var ultimo_dia = +ultima_data[0];
      var ultimo_mes = +ultima_data[1];
      var ultimo_ano = +ultima_data[2];
      this.date.setDate(ultimo_dia);
      this.date.setMonth(ultimo_mes-1);
      this.date.setYear(ultimo_ano);
      this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate()+1);
   }else{
      this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + 1);
      this.date.setDate(1);
   }
   return  novaData(this.date);
}
}

  var DateIndexer = new CellDate(new Date(Date.now()));
  
  
$('#add').click(function(){
    var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1">'+DateIndexer.getNextDate()+'</td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user_data">
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

**Teste quando já existe uma linha:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var data = $('#data1').text();
   var responsavel = $('#data2').text();
   var apoio = $('#data3').text();
   var elementos = $('#data4').text();
   var elementos1 = $('#data5').text();
   if(data != '' && responsavel != '' && apoio != '' && elementos != '' && elementos1 != '')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"./insert",
     method:"POST",
     data:{data:data, responsavel:responsavel, apoio:apoio, elementos:elementos, elementos1:elementos1},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Os campos são de preencimento obrigatório!");
   }
  });
  
function novaData(d){
   var dia  = d.getDate().toString();
   dia = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia;
   var mes  = (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
   mes = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes;
   var ano = d.getFullYear();
   return dia+"-"+mes+"-"+ano;
}
  
  class CellDate{
    constructor( start_date ){
        this.date = start_date;
    }
getNextDate(){
   if($('#user_data tbody tr').length){
      var ultima_data = $("#user_data tbody tr:first td:first").text().trim().split("-");
      var ultimo_dia = +ultima_data[0];
      var ultimo_mes = +ultima_data[1];
      var ultimo_ano = +ultima_data[2];
      this.date.setDate(ultimo_dia);
      this.date.setMonth(ultimo_mes-1);
      this.date.setYear(ultimo_ano);
      this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate()+1);
   }else{
      this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + 1);
      this.date.setDate(1);
   }
   return  novaData(this.date);
}
}

  var DateIndexer = new CellDate(new Date(Date.now()));
  
  
$('#add').click(function(){
    var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1">'+DateIndexer.getNextDate()+'</td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="user_data">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>06-08-2019</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>05-08-2019</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: as duas opções funcionam, mas só se já existir uma linha criada na tabela

Comment: Se não existir linha pega o primeiro dia do mês seguinte, como vc falou.

Comment: mas tentei sem nenhuma linha e aparece NaN-NaN-NaN

Comment: Dá uma olhada aí nos dois exemplos que postei. Um não tem linha e funciona.

Comment: Então realmente não sei o q fazer. Se num lugar funciona e noutro não, aí é complicado.

Comment: Opa! Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: ainda não e o problema está em retornar os dados que existem na base de dados. Aqui mostro o meu código [link](https://jsfiddle.net/517fcq9h/)  e o problema é no `fetch_data();` que existe logo no inicio do javascript, porque é o que faz retornar os dados da base de dados. Se retirar o `fetch_data();` funciona, mas não retorna os dados que já existem na base de dados